# Leave approval by Manager (PM or TL) not by HR in Odoo ERP

Tags: module, odoo, erp, odoo-9

I am new to Odoo currently trying to implement Leave module of HR application from last several days (months...).

I want department head or manager of an employee to grant or reject leave(s) not someone from HR department. HR may approve it after immediate boss's approval for the leave request. (Double validation?)

If it is possible then what needs to be done in Odoo? A step by step instructions would be great.

I posted same question in Odoo forum but couldn't get proper answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems a year ago and tried to use record rules for this requirement. I didn't find a solution so i ended up in overriding the validation process of `hr.holidays`.

In the end the solution wasn't as complex as thought. You just need to implement a method - let's call it `_is_authorized()` - which will check the clicking users authorization. Now just override the validation methods of `hr.holidays`.

```py
@api.multi
def holidays_validate(self):
    for holiday in self:
        employee = holiday.employee_id
        if not self._is_authorized(employee, self.env.user):
            raise exceptions.Warning("Not authorized!")
    return super(hr_holidays, self).holidays_validate()

@api.multi
def holidays_first_validate(self):
    for holiday in self:
        employee = holiday.employee_id
        if not holiday._is_authorized(employee, self.env.user):
            raise exceptions.Warning("Not authorized!")
    return super(hr_holidays, self).holidays_first_validate()

@api.multi
def _is_authorized(self)
    authorized = False
    # your logic here
    return authorized
```

Not the best solution, because a batch validation will be pain in the ass: when one holiday could not be validated, all others won't be, too. But i think this restriction is insignificant.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but could you please inform where should I insert this script? (pardon me for such a basic question).

Comment: Just create a custom module and inherit `hr.holidays`

Comment: So I will have to learn how to create custom modules and inheritance. So it is  quite a task for me as I have never dome anything like that in Odoo other than installing per-built apps and using them. For this problem I have added so called correct rule but that did not help. I have added rule for Leave object as Rule Definition : ['|',('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id),('employee_id.parent_id.user_id','=',user.id) which does not yield anything on my installation.